# CakePHP Accessing Passed Form Data in table afterSave()

Tags: api, cakephp, models, crud, controllers

**SOLVED! I created a $password property in my Entity class thinking I needed to. The password field is added to the Entity through the entire request. None of the code posted below had to be changed.**

I am using friendsofcake/Crud to build a REST api. When I save my User models, I have an afterSave() event that does the password salting and hashing. The POST data sent to my UsersController:add() method includes a ['password'] parameter, but my UsersTable has ['hash','salt'] fields.

Basically, I need to know if and where the POST['password'] parameter is, and if it is available in the UsersTable afterSave() method. Otherwise, my system is hashing and salting empty password strings!

I am new to CakePHP and having trouble finding straightforward answers for 3.*.

Here is the afterSave() method in my UsersTable class.

```
/**
 * Updates Meta information after being created.
 */
public function afterSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, ArrayObject $options)
{
   if($entity->returnAfterSave) return;

   // update the public id
   if(empty($entity->public_id))
   {
     $hashids = new Hashids(static::HASH_SALT, static::HASH_LENGTH);
     $entity->public_id = $hashids->encode($entity->id);
   }

   // generate a password salt
   if(empty($entity->salt))
   {
     $entity->generateSalt();
   }

   // salt and hash the password
   if(empty($entity->hash))
   {
     // NOTE: I figured since the form data
     // is loaded into the entity, I created a $password property
     // in my User Entity class. This assumption may be the problem??
     // Update: It was a bad assumption. Removing said property solved issue.
     $entity->hashPassword();
   }

   // save the changes
   $entity->returnAfterSave = true;
   $this->save($entity);
}
```

Also, I understand that this code will not properly save any new passwords, I will update the code for password changes after my creates are working properly.